# Python 2.7 - How to delete a dictionary using a function?

Tags: python

I have the following function in Python 2.7.5.6:

```
"""
Delete entire *existing* store from memory. Prior to doing so, a backup
copy of the store is saved to disk with the current date and time as
part of the filename:
"""
def drop(store):
    backup(store)
    del store
    ## BUGGY: the store is preserved in its entirety
```

where `store` is a dictionary. If I issue every command in the body of the above function in a Python Shell (IDLE), I get the desired behavior. However, calling the function `drop()` doesn't work; the `store` dictionary is not deleted and is preserved. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could also do

```
def drop(local_store):
    global store
    backup(local_store)
    del store

store = {}   
drop(store)
```

Comment: I was hoping for a function which, **within** said function, would delete the _actual_ `store` dictionary, rather than the copy of it passed as the function's argument. I have other functions such as `insert(store, value)` which, in this example, inserts a new record in the _actual_ `store`.

Comment: Here is the code for the `insert(store, value)` (which works):
`"""
Insert (append as next key) new record into an *existing* store:
"""
def insert(store, value):
    key = nextID(store)
    store[key] = value
    print "Inserted record " + key + ":", store[key]
    print
    return`

Can some kind soul tell me why `insert(store, value)` -- a self-contained function, works whereas my original version of `drop(store)` does not delete the _actual_ `store`?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find a way to properly format (with indentations) my example code for `insert(store, value)`. Any hint about this?

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are simply deleting the local copy of the dictionary `store` that you passed in as a parameter. If you want to delete the original dictionary, just call the `del(store)` method in your code where you actually need to delete `store` as follows:

```
def drop(store):
    backup(store)

store = {}
drop(store)
del store
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make store an object which contains a dictionary; this would give you access to delete it from inside your function:

```
class Store:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data or {}

    def clear(self):
        backup(self.data)
        self.data = {}

store = Store()

def drop(store):
    store.clear()
```